# Как объединить несколько функций "если" в эксель

Tags: excel

Есть 2 таблицы на разных листах, и есть две функции "если", которые дают определенный диапазон значений истины. Вопрос можно ли объединить две функции "если", чтобы они давали только одно значение истина.

=ЕСЛИ(Справочник!$C$2:$C$276='Общая заявка'!$H$1;СТРОКА(Справочник!$C$2:$C$276)-СТРОКА(Справочник!$C$2)+1)

=ЕСЛИ(Справочник!$B$2:$B$276='Общая заявка'!$F$2;СТРОКА(Справочник!$B$2:$B$276)-СТРОКА(Справочник!$B$3)+1)

Comment: *чтобы они давали только одно значение истина* - каждая из формул формирует массив из 275 значений... Покажите пример, возможно, общую формулу можно упростить. Например, выражение `СТРОКА(Справочник!$C$2)+1` всегда равно 3

Comment: @lemonDream, если ответ был полезен, то поставьте плюсик или галочку слева.

Answer (score 1):

Принцип создания формул с несколькими условиями ЕСЛИ заключается в том, что в одном из аргументов формулы (значение_если_ИСТИНА или значение_если_ЛОЖЬ) находится еще одна формула ЕСЛИ.

Таким образом, формула вернет значение МЕНЬШЕ НОЛЯ, так как при первой оценке, результат оказался ЛОЖЬ, а при второй оценке ИСТИНА.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]